# query selector regex to match /blahblah/

Tags: javascript, regex, queryselector

I got a page that contains many a tags. I need to select those who has "/[a-z]/" pattern in their href prop.

I wrote something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/a-z+/']")
```

a sample link that i want this regex matches:

```html
<a href="/blahblah/">blahblah</a>
```

My pattern not working. Any advice?

P.S: The string between two slashes has this pattern:

```
[a-z0-9\._]+
```

P.S2: I did search a lot, asked chatGPT, ...
To match my case, none of the answers was useful. provided duplicate Question recommend to select all elements, then test them in a loop. if this is the only way, i have to change my script scenario. but i think there should be an alternative way that uses directly the selector.

Comment: "*i think there should be an alternative way that uses directly the selector.*" why do you believe that regex is supported in selectors? Did you find any reference for it?

Comment: @VLAZ i don't believe. i just think.. If i'm wrong, i will have to change my scenario. besides, some people suggested patterns that looks fine, but not working.

Comment: So, you don't really have any disagreement with "*You can't really use a regular expression in a selector*" except that you seem to want that to not be true. I can guarantee you that it is true. I don't see a reason to reopen this question based on your wish for the opposite.

Comment: @VLAZ Well as that answer written 10 year ago, i just thought there should be alternative. Thanks for your clearance. trying to change my script then...

Comment: @BehzadSafamanesh *"duplicate Question recommend to select all elements, then test them in a loop."* why all elements? how about all `a` tags with a `href` and only test these? But given your regex, I don't think it will exclude many entries. `[...document.querySelectorAll("a[href]")].filter(a => /[a-z]+/.test(a.href))`

Comment: @thomas +1 for your code. it works as expected. But as i am in position of inspector, I'm trying to write a query selector so the developer team will just use it inside their code. this solution required evaluation in programming dpt. Thanks for your help